# rejected maybe from 8812, cannot find error based on irs search tool

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, free-file-fillable-forms

Issue : Business Rule IND-454 - If `RefundableCTCOrACTCAmt` in the return has a value greater than zero, and [ Schedule 8812 (Form 1040), `MainHomeInUSOverHalfYrInd` or `BonaFidePRResidentInd` is checked ], then it must not be greater than the sum of Schedule 8812 (Form 1040), [(`QlfyChildIncldUnderAgeSSNCnt` multiplied by 3600) and (`QlfyChildOverAgeSSNCnt` multiplied by 3000)].

Issue : Business Rule S8812-F1040-005 - Schedule 8812 (Form 1040), `QlfyChildUnderAgeSSNCnt` must be equal to the number of dependents with `EligibleForChildTaxCreditInd` checked in the return.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the 2nd issue, match the number of Eligible for Child Tax Credit children in your 1040 with the number of children on form 8812.

For the 1st issue, the total refundable child tax credit should not exceed the total on form 8812.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get this fault if you forgot to attach a Form 8812.